# How do I insert array data into a table

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to work through and insert some data into a table that contains an array

```
INSERT INTO SUBURB VALUES (
'Perth', 
'5684',
SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1)
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(391209,6464720 390919,6463010 392833,6463280 392902,6464290 391209,6464720)
    )
);
```

I'm getting syntax error on the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY line and can't work it out.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1)`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. Now it's just moved the syntax error to the secon ordinate set: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "390919". Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a comma here 6463010 392833 and later on 6464290 391209. Replace the spaces (whitespace) with a comma on the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is wrong

```
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(391209,6464720 390919,6463010 392833,6463280 392902,6464290 391209,6464720)
```

The general format of an array in postgressql is

```
'{ val1 delim val2 delim ... }'
```

if this is a one dimension array replace the whitespace with a comma.

If you want to store a multi dimension array use curly brackets

e.g.

```
'{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}'
```

Reference https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html

> To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element
>   values within curly braces and separate them by commas. (If you know
>   C, this is not unlike the C syntax for initializing structures.) You
>   can put double quotes around any element value, and must do so if it
>   contains commas or curly braces. (More details appear below.) Thus,
>   the general format of an array constant is the following: